# Android - Biometrics on Android 9 (SDK 28) - Phone has face recognition available but BiometricManager returns null

Tags: android, face-recognition, biometrics

I am adding Biometrics to my app for when its available on the device.
I am using a Samsung phone running Android 9... the phone has face recognition and I have my face registered.

The issue is, when i use `BiometricManager.canAuthenticate()` to ask the device what Biometrics are available, it fails saying "no Biometrics are available on the device". Further digging revealed that the `BiometricManager.canAuthenticate()` method only checks for facial recognition if the SDK is >= Android Q (SDK 29)... this makes no sense at all.

If I ignore the `canAuthenticate()` method result and attempt to display a `BiometricPrompt`, it works 100% successfully... the user is prompted, the face is recognized, and I am able to login to the app using only face recognition. Furthermore, all of the Authentication method callbacks work, `onAuthenticationError` method knows if Biometrics are enrolled or not...

If this works on Android 9, why the **F** is the BiometricsManager only checking when the SDK is Android 10?

If one of my users has a similar device as me (Android 9 with face recognition) and they try to enable it in my app and they get a popup saying "your device has no biometric authentication available" that will seem like a pretty big flaw...

Is there any other way to confirm face recognition biometrics is available? Because the documented solution is not correct based on my case.

Comment: Any solution on this?

Comment: No, seems there is no way to get this on < 29

Comment: yes I had posted it in google issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162573670 they also marked it as infeasible

Comment: When I did research the latest, there was only face recognition on PIxel 4. The face recognition on other devices is not secure enough